# Adding, Subtracting, Dividing, and Multiplying two binary numbers stored in boolean arrays

Tags: java, binary

I need help with making a Binary calculator. I am trying to add, subtract, divide, and multiply two binary numbers that are stored as a boolean[] array in java. I'm pretty stuck so some help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

```
private static boolean[] multiply(boolean[] bits1, boolean[] bits2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private static boolean[] subtract(boolean[] bits1, boolean[] bits2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private static boolean[] add(boolean[] bits1, boolean[] bits2) {

    return null;
}
private static Object[] divide(boolean[] bits1, boolean[] bits2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried converting to an int or long then multiplying then converting back into a boolean array?

Comment: That is a good idea. How would I convert the array into a long and back again?

Comment: The method declarations look quiet good for the start. Where they specified this way in your homework? Do you understand binary representation of numbers? Would you know how a '7' for example would look in binary format? Start with addition.

Comment: Can you explain why your 4th method returns an Array of Object, not Boolean?

Answer (score 0):

First convert to a long:

```
long boolToLong(boolean[] b){
   long sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
      if(b[i])sum += Math.pow(2, i);
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Then, muliply/add/divide/subtract, Then, convert back to a boolean array:

```
boolean[] longToBool(long l){
   boolean[] result = new boolean[1+(int) Math.ceil(Math.log(l)/Math.log(2))];
   for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      result[i] = ((l%(Math.pow(2, i+1))) >= Math.pow(2, i))
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework with the goal of understanding the binary format. I guess your method is not helpful - only to check the results for correctness, maybe.

Comment: In longToBool, the parenthesis don't match. Adding 2 closing braces to the line end yields to the result, that `boolToLong (longToBool (x)) != x` for harmless x. Maybe you have a look at JShell (comes with java9), which is fine for running code snippets like that.

Comment: Please test your code before you actually post it in an answer

Comment: Sorry, honest mistake, is fixed now. I normally do test my code but I forgot to this time.

Comment: But you don't test with negative numbers, do you? :) I'm a bit surprised by your sort order, i would consider 0111 to be seven and hence false-true-true-true, but the debate about little-vs-big-endian is still heated, we needn't fight it here. :)

Comment: I didn't test it with negative numbers because it's easier to just use a xor gate for negatives and not convert negatives to longs